# How to generate table tr based on a total number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote the blow code to generate tr for my table based on a total count .
there is a input type text that contains a number and i want to generatge tr for my table according to that number
but it is not working .
here is my snippet :

```js
function findTotal(){
    var table = $("#travells");
    var rowNum = parseInt($("#total").val(), 10);
    var resultHtml = '';
    
 for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
 resultHtml += ["<tr>", 
  "<td>", 
   (i+1),
  "</td>",
  '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
  '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
  '</tr>'].join("\n");
 }  
 
 table.html(resultHtml);
    return false; 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="findTotal()">
<input type="text" value="8" id="total"/>

<table id="travells">
     <thead>
     <tr class="travelcounting">
     <th>name</th>
     <th>gender</th>
     <th>country</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="Name" readonly/></td>
     <td class="columns"><input type="text" id="gender" readonly/></td>
     <td class="columns"><input type="text" id="country" readonly/></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>

</body>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? are there any erroneous logs?

Comment: What's not working, what errors do you see in console ?

Comment: @nadavvadan  my code isn't working. and shows error here. but i don't have this error in my pc and it's just not working without any error

Comment: You have a syntax error. Remove the  `)` at the end of the function declaration.

Comment: @nadavvadan  i just removed it

Comment: If it's still not working, I'd suggest you add `debugger` statements and/or `console.log`s and see where the code breaks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#travells");
    var rowNum = parseInt($("#total").val(), 10);
    var resultHtml = '';
    
 for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
 resultHtml += ["<tr>", 
  "<td>", 
   (i+1),
  "</td>",
  '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
  '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
  '</tr>'].join("\n");
 }  
 
 table.html(resultHtml);
    return false; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="8" id="total"/>

<table id="travells">
     <thead>
     <tr class="travelcounting">
     <th>name</th>
     <th>gender</th>
     <th>country</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="Name" readonly/></td>
     <td class="columns"><input type="text" id="gender" readonly/></td>
     <td class="columns"><input type="text" id="country" readonly/></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When constructing these kind of strings, the new template literals from ES6 are a good fit. See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
function findTotal(){
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var rowNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value, 10);
  var resultHtml = '';

  for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
    resultHtml += `<tr>
      <td>
        ${(i + 1)}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
      </td>
    </tr>`;
  };
  body.innerHTML = resultHtml;
};
```

```html
<body onload="findTotal()">
<input type="text" value="8" id="total"/>

<table id="travells">
     <thead>
     <tr class="travelcounting">
     <th>name</th>
     <th>gender</th>
     <th>country</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="Name" readonly/></td>
     <td class="columns"><input type="text" id="gender" readonly/></td>
     <td class="columns"><input type="text" id="country" readonly/></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#RowC").on("click",function(){
  var TRCnt=$("tbody >tr").length;
  for(var i=TRCnt;i< (parseInt($("#RowNum").val())+TRCnt);i++){
     let tr=$("<tr/>");
     let inputName=$("<input/>",{type:"text",name:"name",placeholder:"name",value:i+1});
     let inputGender=$("<input/>",{type:"text",name:"gender",placeholder:"gender"});
     let inputCountry=$("<input/>",{type:"text",name:"country",placeholder:"country"});
     tr.append($("<td/>").html(inputName)); 
     tr.append($("<td/>").html(inputGender));
       tr.append($("<td/>").html(inputCountry));

     $("tbody").append(tr);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="RowNum" />
<input type="button" id="RowC" value="click" />
<hr>
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the jquery code:

```
 $("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var table = $("#resultTable");
    var rowNum = parseInt($("#table-row-num").val(), 10);
    var resultHtml = '';

    for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
        resultHtml += ["<tr>", 
     "<td>", 
      (i+1),
     "</td>",
     '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
     '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
     '</tr>'].join("\n");
    }  

    table.html(resultHtml);
    return false; 
});
```

I wish you luck with implementation. :)

The Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fpd8dwtw/20/

Comment: i want to run my code on body loaded not submit anything

Comment: but when onload body the function run only one and can't edit the row number what do you want exactly

Comment: this code run on onload body and you can edit the row number of `submit`